# Show that X and |X| are uncorrelated but not independent

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am just starting to learn probability theory and working through some concrete examples in the book.

Let $\Omega = \{-1, 0, 1\}$, $p = \frac{1}{|\Omega|} = \frac{1}{3}, X(\omega) = \omega$ and $|X| = 1$.

Show that X and |X| are uncorrelated but not independent.

I've shown that they are uncorrelated using the standard definition, but I'm not sure how to show they're not independent.

I've started out with $P(X = \omega, |X| = 1) = \frac{1}{3} * 1 = \frac{1}{3}$ for each value in $\Omega$, but that is the same as $P(X = \omega)* P(|X| = 1)$.

I might be missing some basic definitions here. Please advise me.

Comment: Are you sure that $\vert X \vert =1 $ ? Shouldn't $\vert X \vert $ denote the absolute value of $X(\omega)$ instead of the constant random variable $1$ ?

Comment: The notation was a bit confusing. I assumed they meant the size of $X(\omega)$.

Answer (score 2):

$\underline{\mathrm{Recall}}$ : independence $\Leftrightarrow \mathbb{P}(A \cap B) = \mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)$. Yet, in the present case, you have for instance $\mathbb{P}(X=0 \cap |X|=1) = \mathbb{P}(\emptyset) = 0$, while $\mathbb{P}(X=0)\mathbb{P}(|X|=1) = \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{3} = \frac{2}{9} \neq 0$. In consequence, $X$ and $|X|$ are not independent by contraposition.

Comment: Your notation for $\vert X \vert $ does not match up with the question. In the post it looks like $\vert X \vert$ denotes the constant $1$ and not the absolute value of $X$.

Comment: @Digitallis  Hmm, you seem right. But at the same the question would become void of sense, since a constant random variable is always independent. I wonder if the OP made a mistake when he wrote his question.